# Запрет перехода на другую вкладку TabLayout, если в текущей есть ошибки

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout

Как отловить событие перехода на другую вкладку TabLayout, и если в текущей есть ошибки, то запретить переход и оставаться в текущей вкладке?

Comment: желательно уточнить какие ошибки

Comment: например, не заполнено обязательное поле и нельзя переходить на другие вкладки, пока не заполнить это поле.

Comment: добавьте в вопросу код для переключения вкладок чтобы другие пользователи понимали о чем речь идет

Answer (score 0):

Отключить переход на другую вкладку можно таким способом:

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
setupTabIcons();

LinearLayout tabStrip = ((LinearLayout)mTabLayout.getChildAt(0));
    for(int i = 0; i < tabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
        tabStrip.getChildAt(i).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

только уже подставьте под свое условие, какое у вас в программе.

Comment: условие необходимо проверять при попытке переходить на другую закладку. Если условие не выполнено, тогда не переходить на выбранную закладку. Ситуация такая есть вкладки А и В. Текущая А. Заполняю поля. Одно обязательное поле не заполнил. Нажал на закладку В. В этот момент проверяется заполненность всех полей. В данном случае одно осталось не заполненным. Не переходить на закладку В и оставаться в закладке А. Вот чего я добиваюсь.